# Find minimal integer $n>1$ for which $2^n > n^{1000}$.

Tags: real-analysis

Find the minimum integer $n>1$ for which $2^n > n^{1000}$.

I have taken the $log$ on both sides, but not reached any result. I would appreciate if anybody will solve it accurately. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Using [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%2F(log_2(x))%3D1000), we can know that minimum integer is $n=13747$.

Comment: That link does not show the solution. [This one does](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve+x%2F(log_2(x))%3D1000), however, because I put in the word "solve."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Taking $\log$ on both sides, you get

$$n \log 2 > 1000 \log n$$
or $$n - \frac{1000}{\log 2} \log n >0$$

This resembles the upper left triangular portion of the real plane formed by the straight line $$n - \frac{1000}{\log 2} \log n = 0$$

Hope this helps.

Comment: And, once more, appears Lambert function !

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**
You can look, equivalently, at the inequality $n > \frac{1000}{\ln 2} \ln n$.

Now, study the function $f\colon x> 0 \mapsto x - \frac{1000}{\ln 2} \ln x$ (with the usual tools: differentiation, etc.) to see starting at which value it is increasing. (It's not hard to see that $f$ is decreasing, then increasing). This will help you figure out the minimum value $x_0$ such that $f(x) > 0$ for all $x> x_0$.

Answer (score 3):

We have n ≥ 2. Therefore $2^n > 2^{1000}$, which makes n ≥ 1,001.

We have n ≥ 1,001. Therefore $2^n > 1001^{1000}$, which makes n ≥ 9,967.226 or n ≥ 9,968.

We have n ≥ 9,968. Therefore $2^n > 9968^{1000}$, which makes n ≥ 13,283.088 or n ≥ 13,284.

We have n ≥ 13,284. Therefore $2^n > 13284^{1000}$, which makes n ≥ 13,697.402 or n ≥ 13,698.

We have n ≥ 13,698. Therefore $2^n > 13698^{1000}$, which makes n ≥ 13,741.677 or n ≥ 13,742.

We have n ≥ 13,742. Therefore $2^n > 13742^{1000}$, which makes n ≥ 13,746.303 or n ≥ 13,747.

Now $log_2 (13,747) = 13,746.829$, which makes $2^{13,747} > 13,747^{1,000}$.

Comment: +1.  Your solution illustrates an intuitive, iterative process!  =)

Answer (score 1):

You need to rewrite the equation so that you can apply numeric evaluations. If not you hit Lambert W function as a solution, which I will not utter here.

So let us start. We need to find $n$ so that $n-2^{\frac{n}{1000}}=0$. This one has two solutions and we need the larger one, at least integer part of it.

We can immediately notice that $13 < \frac{n}{1000} < 14$ because $2^{13}=8192$ and $2^{14}=16384$. Obviously both are far away from 13000 and 14000, but 14000 looks better

$$14000-x-2^{\frac{14000-x}{1000}}=0$$
$$14000-x-2^{14}2^{-\frac{x}{1000}}=0$$
$$14000-x-16384 \cdot 2^{-\frac{x}{1000}}=0$$

Now it comes to trying $x=\frac{100}{2},x=\frac{100}{3},x=\frac{100}{4},...$ because we get expressions with $\sqrt{2},\sqrt[3]{2},\sqrt[4]{2},\sqrt[5]{2}$ and we can safely calculate any of these.

$14000-250-y-16384 \cdot 2^{-\frac{250+y}{1000}}=0$

$$13750-y-8192\sqrt[4]{8} 2^{-\frac{y}{1000}}=0$$

Now this part is very small $\frac{y}{1000}$ so we can try replacing it knowing $e^{1+x} \approx x$.

$$13750-y-8192\sqrt[4]{8}(1-\frac{y\log(2)}{1000})=0$$

This is linear equation and the solution is

$$y=\frac{250(4096\sqrt[4]{8}-6875)}{1024\sqrt[4]{8}\log(2)-125}$$

To get to the bottom of this we will try to prove $3 < y < 4$.

$$z=\frac{250(4096\sqrt[4]{8}-6875)}{1024\sqrt[4]{8}\log(2)-125}-3$$

$$z=\frac{(1024000 -3072 \log(2))2^{3/4}-1718375}{1024\cdot 2^{3/4} \log(2)-125}$$

This is obvious $1024 \cdot 2^{3/4} \log(2)-125 > 1000$ because $1024\cdot 2^{3/4} \log(2)> 875$ and $2^{3/4} \log(2) > 1$ because $\log^4(2)>\frac{1}{8}$ and this is obvious since $\log^4(2)>0.6^4=0.1296>\frac{1}{8}$

So it remains to prove that $$0 < (1024000 -3072 \log(2))2^{3/4}-1718375 < 1000$$

This is bringing it to $1000 > 1719375-1024\cdot 8^{1/4} (1000-\log(8)) > 0$

Now $1680>\frac{1719375}{1024}>1679$ so we can divide by 1024

This is bringing us to $\frac{1000}{1024} > 1679+\frac{79}{1024}-8^{1/4} (1000-\log(8)) > 0$

Further $\frac{1000}{1024} > 1679+\frac{79}{1024}-8^{1/4} 1000+8^{1/4}\log(8)) > 0$

We establish

$$\frac{7}{2} > 8^{1/4}\log(8) > 3$$

$$8^{1/4}\log(8) > 3 \implies  2^{3/4}\log(2) > 1 $$ and we had this already above.

Second part is

$$7 > 2\cdot8^{1/4}\log(8)$$

$$\frac{3500}{1681} > \frac{1750}{841} > \log(8)$$

$$\frac{1750}{841} > \frac{208}{100} > 3 \log(2)$$

$$1750 \cdot 100 > 841 \cdot 208 $$

$$21875 > 21866 $$

This makes it all

$$\frac{1000}{1024} > 1679+\frac{79}{1024}-8^{1/4} 1000+3 > 0$$
$$\frac{1000}{1024} > 1679+\frac{79}{1024}-8^{1/4} 1000+\frac{7}{2} > 0$$

or

$$1679+\frac{79}{1024}-\frac{1000}{1024}+3 < 8^{1/4} 1000 < 1679+\frac{79}{1024}+3$$

$$1679+\frac{79}{1024}-\frac{1000}{1024}+\frac{7}{2} < 8^{1/4} 1000 < 1679+\frac{79}{1024}+\frac{7}{2}$$

which makes it together

$$1679+\frac{79}{1024}-\frac{1000}{1024}+\frac{7}{2} < 8^{1/4} 1000 < 1679+\frac{79}{1024}+3$$

or

$$1.679+\frac{79}{1024000}-\frac{1}{1024}+\frac{7}{2000} < 8^{1/4} < 1.679+\frac{79}{1024000}+\frac{3}{1000}$$

This is indeed

$$1.679-\frac{921}{1024000}+\frac{7}{2000} < 8^{1/4} < 1.679+\frac{3}{1000}$$

or

$$1.679-\frac{800}{1000000}+\frac{7}{2000} < 8^{1/4} < 1.679+\frac{3}{1000}$$

$$1.679-\frac{8}{10000}+\frac{7}{2000} < 8^{1/4} < 1.679+\frac{3}{1000}$$

making it all

$$1.6817 < 8^{1/4} < 1.6820$$

We can calculate $8^{1/4}$ simply by taking $8^{1/4}=\sqrt{2\sqrt{2}}$ and there are quick and efficient algorithms for $\sqrt{.}$

Or we can do the next. Find only $\sqrt{8}=2\sqrt{2}\approx 2.8284$ and prove that $1.6817^2 < 2.8284 < 2.8285 < 1.6820^2$

And indeed we would have $1.6817^2 < 2.8282 < 2.8284 < 2\sqrt{2} < 2.8285 < 2.829 < 1.6820^2$

This means that we have the integer value finally as

$$13500+250-3=13747$$